# Undefined control sequence for {align*}

Tags: align

Could someone tell me what have I done wrong here. I keep looking but seems I cannot find the mistake:

```
\begin{align*}
a_n=\frac{L}{n^2\pi^2}(sin(\frac{4n\pi}{10})
-\frac{4n\pi}{10}cos(\frac{4n\pi}{10})+
\\frac{2L}{3n^2\pi^2}(-n\picos(n\pi)-sin(\frac{4n\pi}{10}
+\frac{4n\pi}{10} cos(\frac{4n\pi}{10}))
+\frac{2L}{3n^2\pi^2}(-cos(n\pi)
+cos(\frac{4n\pi}{10}))
\end{align*}
```

so when I want to build it, it keeps telling me "Undefined control sequence "

All the previous code worked fine before I typed this

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Try replacing `\picos` with `\pi cos` or, better yet, `\pi\cos`. And, while you're at it, change `\\frac` to `\\ \frac`.

Comment: Plus all sin to `\sin`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to inserting a space after `\pi` in "`\picos`" and changing `\\frac` to `\\ \frac`, you should also change all instances of `sin` and `cos` to `\sin` and `\cos`, respectively, and insert an additional line break. Since you're using an `align*` environment, do provide suitable alignment points ("`&`") in all three rows. You should also enlarge the sizes of most (but not all) round parentheses. A separate issue: some parentheses appear have gone AWOL and need to be (re)supplied. Finally, to improve legibility and parsability of the expression, consider replacing the "outer" round parentheses with square brackets.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align*" environment
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a_n 
&= \frac{L}{n^2\pi^2}\Bigl[\sin\Bigl(\frac{4n\pi}{10}\Bigr)
  -\frac{4n\pi}{10}\cos\Bigl(\frac{4n\pi}{10}\Bigr)\Bigr]\\
&\quad
  +\frac{2L}{3n^2\pi^2}\Bigl[-n\pi \cos(n\pi)
  -\sin\Bigl(\frac{4n\pi}{10}\Bigr)
  +\frac{4n\pi}{10} \cos\Bigl(\frac{4n\pi}{10}\Bigr)\Bigr]\\
&\quad
  +\frac{2L}{3n^2\pi^2}\Bigl[-\cos(n\pi)
  +\cos\Bigl(\frac{4n\pi}{10}\Bigr)\Bigr]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```